# Oracle + Obtener el digito verificdor desde un campo RUT

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Estimad@s,

Favor su apoyo ya que necesito obtener desde una tabla X el dígito verificador de un campo Rut.

```
TABLA!
RUTCLIENTE|NOMBRE|APELLIDO
224345631 | Juan | Soto
67768906  | Ana  | Molina
```

Sus respectivos DV son 1 y 6, cabe señalar que los RUT no tienen el mismo largo.

LA idea es a partir de esta TABLA1 insertar el RUT y DV en una TABLA2.

```
TABLA2
RUTCLIENTE|DV|NOMBRE|APELLIDO
22434563  |1 |Juan  |Soto 
6776890   |6 |Ana   |Molina
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: De esta forma obtuve solo el rut sin dv.
SELECT SUBSTR(rutcliente,1, LENGTH(rutcliente)-1 FROM TABLA1)

Comment: Lo que necesito ahora es solo obtener el DV del rut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu caso particular, la consulta sería algo como esto:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA2(RUTCLIENTE,
                          DV,
                          NOMBRE,
                          APELLIDO)
   SELECT SUBSTR(rutcliente,1, LENGTH(rutcliente)-1) FROM TABLA1,
   SELECT SUBSTR(rutcliente,-1, 1) FROM TABLA1,
          NOMBRE,
          APELLIDO
     FROM TABLA1
```

Utilizando tu misma consulta.

Para obtener el dígito del rut se utiliza:

SELECT SUBSTR(rutcliente,-1, 1) FROM TABLA1

El segundo campo `(-1)` indica que la cadena comienza a contar desde atrás para adelante.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Harifo, tema resuelto.